# 'which' command outputs nothing in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to figure out path of the executable command, but `which` says nothing. Why ? So and when it's usual case for `which`to return nothing about command's path. path is hidden/inaccessible for some types of executables or ...

```
which sdk
```

sdk - it's [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/)

Comment: Do you have a program named `sdk` installed in a directory in your path?

Comment: If `sdk` is a valid command in your shell, use `type sdk` to see what it is

Comment: @thatotherguy outputs 'sdk is a function'. what does it mean ?

Comment: It means that `sdk` is a function defined in the current shell, and not a program on disk somewhere

Comment: @thatotherguy oh, It's kinda indistinguishable on the surface. Thank you! I was just wondering how `sdk` can change PATH variable from the outside script, and now it's clear. it can't. It is a part of this shell instance :)

Answer (score 2):

If `which exe` does not return a string it means there is not executable item (script or binary) called "exe" on your path.

You can also check the return code:

```
which exe
echo $?
```

If the status is 0 then exe was found. If the status in non zero then it wasn't (or some error occurred depending on your version of "which")

As per comments: `type` may also help - it can identify shell builtins and functions available to the current shell - these items won't show up with `which`